# How to compare the fromdate and todate in Spring MongoDB filter query

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, arraylist

I am fetching the documents from MongoDB in between fromdate and todate. There is one field in all documents called 'lastActive'. lastActive field is date string in mongodb documents. I need to compare lastActive field documents with greater than **fromDate** and less than **toDate**. I am not sure how to write find find query in SpringBoot, I have written, but is giving zero records.

```
Active_userlist=profile_collection.find(Filters.and(Filters.gte("lastActive", 
fromDate),Filters.lte("lastActive",toDate))).into(new ArrayList<Document>));
```

Can someone please help me to get appropriate document within date range.
**Note: I am using postman to call this API, I have provided fromdate and todate in ResponseBody of postman.**

Answer (score 0):

You're probably comparing the date field with string coming from API. Convert the date from string to Date Object.

Ex:

```
String DB_FORMAT_DATETIME = "yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss"

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DB_FORMAT_DATETIME);

formatter.parse(dateStr); // dateStr is string date received from API
```

Comment: Can u help me with the query

Comment: are you using mongo template in spring data to interact with MongoDB?

Comment: Hello I am using MongoRepository to interact with MongoDB